# Access class instance from another function - getDefinitionByName(AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a function, sceneLoader, that will instantiate an object of the Class Scene1 from a string using getDefinitionByName. I then want to access a function (sceneHandler) in Scene1, from another function.

```
public class Main extends MovieClip{

    private var sceneNumber:int = 1;
    private var SceneRef:Class;
    private var sceneString:String;

    public function Main(){
        sceneLoader();
        responseHandler();
    }

    private function sceneLoader():void{
        sceneString = "Scene" + int(sceneNumber);
        SceneRef = getDefinitionByName(sceneString) as Class;
        var scene = new SceneRef();
        addChild(scene);
    }
    private function responseHandler():void{
        scene.sceneHandler(); //Obviously this will not work
    }
}
```

Class Scene1

```
public class Scene1 extends MovieClip{
    public function sceneHandler():void{
        //Do something
    }
}
```

The problem is that scene is out of scope. I cannot instantiate Scene1 outside the function as I need to first call getDefinitionByName. I also want to keep the function for loading scenes later on.
How can I call sceneHandler from responseHandler?

EDIT: I've tried

```
public class Main extends MovieClip{

    private var sceneNumber:int = 1;
    private var SceneRef:Class;
    private var sceneString:String;

    public function Main(){
        sceneLoader();
        responseHandler();
    }

    private function sceneLoader():void{
        addChild(getScene());//Does not work
    }

    private function responseHandler():void{
        getScene().sceneHandler(); //Works now
    }

    private function getScene():Object{
        sceneString = "Scene" + int(sceneNumber);
        SceneRef = getDefinitionByName(sceneString) as Class;
        var scene = new SceneRef();
        //addChild(getScene());//This does work but doesn't suit my need
        return scene;
     }
}
```

Now I can't add the object to the stage.
I get the Error:

> Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just forgot to cast as a DisplayObject.

```
public class Main extends MovieClip{

    private var sceneNumber:int = 1;
    private var SceneRef:Class;
    private var sceneString:String;

    public function Main(){
        sceneLoader();
        responseHandler();
    }

    private function sceneLoader():void{
        addChild(getScene() as DisplayObject);
    }

    private function responseHandler():void{
        getScene().sceneHandler();
    }

    private function getScene():Object{
        sceneString = "Scene" + int(sceneNumber);
        SceneRef = getDefinitionByName(sceneString) as Class;
        var scene = new SceneRef();
        return scene;
     }
}
```

Obviously:

```
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
```